# How do I fix gnunet issues connected with upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, email, postfix

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Countless times during the upgrade, and several times every time I reboot since then, I get:

> System Program Problem Detected

It always says:

> Sorry, Ubuntu 16.0.4 has experienced an internal error

and it identifies `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gnunet/libexec/gnunet-service-core` (or `-nse` or `-transport` or `-mesh`) as the executable that failed. The detailed error message always says:

> [executable name] crashed with SIGABRT in GNUNET_abort()

Everything's been running absymally slow since I upgraded. If you recognize this gnunet problem, and the slow execution speed is one of the symptoms of that problem, then that would be wonderful. Otherwise, the slow speed is a separate problem I'll need help with.

There's some associated messages:

```
postfix/pickup[7897]: warning: B01592A011E: message has been queued for 435 days
... warning: hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/virtual_alias.db: no such file or directory
... warning: hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias lookup errorr for "root@hostname"
... warning: B01592A011E: virtual_alias_masp map lookup problem for root@hostname - message not accepted, try again later
```

However - I suspect that may be a different issue. I just installed 16.04 on August 5th, so that can't be the cause of something that started 435 days ago.
I've discovered that postfix is a mail server, which makes me suspect that this might be connected to the windows that occasionally come up asking me whether I want to send in a problem report. Could it be that all of those problem reports are sitting in a queue waiting for me to set up a mail server? I normally use my ISP's mail server - I had no intention of setting up one of my own. If that is indeed the problem, is there some configuration I can set to make it use my ISP's mail server?